# measurment of a cut cylindrical object, by a primitive way

Tags: measurements, history

If I take a hose and cut it at the middle along its width (=horizontal cross-section), but I don't cut it completely into to parts, but around half of it remain connected, in a way it's difficult to determine by eyes sight if it's exactly half or not while I need it exactly in the half.

The issue is that I need a primitive way to check it while I'm outside in nature (not by electronic equipment etc.), but maybe other available means such as string / thread / yarn / wire (as I heard in past but couldn't find it again). Is there an accurate way to do so? (How did people do it in the ancient times?)